# Increment thousands of values in and XML file, then do that across many files in a folder

Tags: xml, powershell, variables, foreach, increment

I have been struggling for days and nights and I just can't get it right.

I have an XML file called DDINP, in this DDINP XML file there are transaction id tags:

```
<TxId>0001/2021-04-20/000499605</TxId>
```

There are many of these DDINP files - currently 4100 files, which is over 2.6Million of these transaction id's in total.

All of these DDINP's also write when created, to a DRINP file where that transaction id from the DDINP looks like this:

```
<OrgnlTxId>0003/2021-04-09/000499605</OrgnlTxId>
```

These DRINP files are created to be used the following day. They need to match the brother DDINP file.

There are a few reason why but, I need to control the last six digits for uniqueness of that DDINP file, but also then need to write that value to the DRINP file. I had code which randomizes the transaction id but it doesnt help as I cant get that value written into the DRINP files.

My code: (Also, why does this code not write a unique value for all txid's in the xml file?):

```
#set-executionpolicy remotesigned

#Set your path here, on the first folder.
$path = "C:\Users\Dell\Downloads\FNB 2 Trans\File Creation\DDINP"

#Get the list of all *.txt, with recursivity
$list = Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -Include "*.xml"

#Replace the elements
[regex]$initialvar=  '<TxId>(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)</TxId>'

$newvar = $null



foreach($item in $list)
{
auto-increment

#you get a random value between 111111 and 2222222 
$newvar = (Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 999999).ToString('000000')
                              
#here in each file, you replace the initial value(789) with the new value
(Get-Content $item) -replace $initialvar,"<TxId>0001/2021-04-20/$newvar</TxId>" | Set-Content $item
                                          

}
```

SO my questions are:
1 - how do I increment all the ID's found starting from 000001 to 999999 in an xml file and then continue to the next file in the folder

2 - why doesn't it uniquely generate a incremented value in the xml file? they were all

```
<TxId>0001/2021-04-20/1</TxId> 
<TxId>0001/2021-04-20/1</TxId> 
<TxId>0001/2021-04-20/1</TxId>
```

The code that I posted is a randomizer, I tried with Incrementing code but I cant get that right.

Appreciate guys

Comment: You're only generating a random number *once* per file (i.e. ```$newvar = (Get-Random ...```) and then replacing *all* the regex matches in that file with the same value. If you want each match to have a different value you'll need to ```foreach``` over them and generate a random number inside that loop.

Comment: As an aside, you might be better off converting the file to an ```[xml]``` object and manipulating that rather than using a regex

Comment: You are also replacing the first and second part inside the `<TxId>` tag with hardcoded `0001/2021-04-20`. Is whatever was in there before unimportant or should it be kept original?

Comment: Hi all - thanks for the replies, and I will search further from what info Mclayton provided. Theo. Yes, that needs to be hardcoded, as I go over with Notepad++ and change that date in there later on